# Why there are Duplicate methods in Rest-assured like statusCode() and getStatusCode()?

Tags: rest-assured

Why there are Duplicate methods in Rest-assured framework like `response.statusCode()` and `response.getStatusCode()` ?

There are multiple duplicate methods in Rest-assured like : `response.getBody()` and `response.body()`, `response.getBody().asString()` and `response.asString()`, `response.statusLine()` and `response.getStatusLine()`, `response.getHeader("Content-Type")` and `response.header("Content-Type"`), and `response.contentType()` and `response.getContentType()`, etc.

What is the reason behind designing multiple methods for same purpose ?